# Flutter: simple_bloc_observer.onError

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

Anytime I try to run the following code, it fails to compile, the error is in line 17 of the code, it is in the onError string that is right after Future, looking forward to your response.

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SimpleBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
    print(event);
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    print(transition);
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onError(Cubit cubit, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) async {
    print(error);
    super.onError(cubit, error, stackTrace);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `Cubit cubit` to `BlocBase bloc`

code snippet

```
void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace)
```

[bloc source code](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/27c3f47e415198b4eeb6435c59a918f4277f180d/packages/bloc/lib/src/bloc_observer.dart#L41)

```
  // Called whenever an [error] is thrown in any [Bloc] or [Cubit].
  /// The [stackTrace] argument may be [StackTrace.empty] if an error
  /// was received without a stack trace.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {}
```

[example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/27c3f47e415198b4eeb6435c59a918f4277f180d/packages/bloc/example/main.dart#L31%3Cbr%3E)

code snippet

```
  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print('onError -- bloc: ${bloc.runtimeType}, error: $error');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
```

Comment: @MohamedEl-Alkamy, Glad to help. I did not revise my answer, you can see edit history. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: This answer saved me after a week of struggling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For *[flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)* you need to [migrate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) with some changes

`v6.1.x`

```
  @override
  void onError(Cubit cubit, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {...}
```

`v7.0.0`

```
  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {...}
```

Your first positional argument must be `BlocBase bloc` here.